# Problems with middle name

Tags: bibtex

In my literature directory it only shows the first and last name, but I want to see the middle name as well. My codes is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}  
\begin{document}
  \bibliography{BIB}
\end{document}
```

And in my bibfile:

```
@phdthesis {RK,
title={{R}unge-{K}utta Methods for Stochastic Differential Equations},
author={Burrage, {P.M.}},
year={1999},
school={The University of Queensland, Brisbane}
}
```

I want that it lookks like:

> Burrage, P. M. (1999). Runge-Kutta...

but it looks like:

> Burrage, P. (1999). Runge-Kutta...

How can I change that?

Answer (score 6):

The BibTeX file format *requires* a space between each name even when they are given simply as abbreviated initials. Thus you need to have

```
author = {Burrage, P. M.}
```